# How to call "OpenURL" function of Appdelegate from UI Xctest

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, xctestcase

My application contains "OpenIn" functionality i.e. user can share any file to my application. I want to test this using UI testing in Xcode.

1. How do I access Appdelegate's/UIApplicaiton's "OpenURL" method in XctestCase class?
2. How can I show a "OpenIn" window i.e. share with application popup where I can share the file?

Answer (score 0):

It may be more suitable to do this without UI testing. Then the tests can directly call the desired app delegate methods directly.

Comment: In my application, first step is to share file from "Files" app to my app. And then app has screens to handle that file. Other wise If user launch app directly, app shows instruction screen only with how to share the file detail. So i want to know how do I go to App by sharing file using UI Xctest and not by programming.